# Need example and working Security Token Service (STS)?

Tags: cryptography, key-management

Can anyone explain or post any link to a simple example and introduction about the
Security Token Service (STS)?

Answer (score 2):

Some posts I've written (.NET based, but basic enough):

- http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2010/10/30/the-basics-of-building-a-security-token-service.aspx
- http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2011/07/04/part-4-secure-architecture.aspx (section on *authentication*)
- http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2011/02/22/multiple-identity-providers-in-a-multi-tenant-system-using-access-control-services.aspx
- http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2011/01/31/the-problem-with-claims-based-authentication.aspx
- http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2010/10/18/what-makes-claims-based-authentication-secure.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's anything I'd call "simple", but there are [Kerberos](http://www.gria.org/documentation/5.3/manual/client-management-user-guide/tt/using-the-kerberos-sts), [Sharepoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806864.aspx), and [Apache](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/setting-up-sts.html) guides. Simply [searching](http://www.google.com/search?q=security%20token%20service) for the term brings up many of those pages.